# Why isn't DiscordJS Function properly and sending a can not find module error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, replit

I updated the node and discord.js version of my bot(Hosted on Repl.it), and since then I can not seem to use the DiscordJS Library. I have two bots I am using, one is working properly even though it is like the latest version while the other one, which I updated, is not working properly. So I thought there must be something wrong with my Repl(Project), so I created a new one. However, that still does not work. It throws the error:

```
Require stack:
- /home/runner/Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /home/runner/Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
- /home/runner/Bot/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
```

I tried to debug it myself and first omit the DiscorJS Library and run the program with a `console.log()` statement, and it works without an error. So there is something wrong with either NodeJS or DiscordJS. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after some more debugging.

1. Type `npm install node@16` in the shell.
2. Create a new file on the main directory of the Repl with the name `.replit` and type `run = "npx node index.js"` in it.
   Now try to run the file. It should work with the DiscordJS Library